# How to change kernel parameter with GRUB2?

Tags: grub2, kernel

This is not a duplicate. I want to change the following kernel parameters which I find in the default Linux kernel of Ubuntu 16.04LTS/32 4.4.0-59-generic:

```
CONFIG_MODULE_SIG=y
CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_ALL=y
CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_UEFI=y
CONFIG_MODULES_USE_ELF_REL=y
```

Of course I can recompile the kernel but I want to avoid it for several reasons. Can I change [temporally or permanently](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter?rq=1) `grub` like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=" … CONFIG_MODULE_SIG=n CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_ALL=n CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_UEFI=n CONFIG_MODULES_USE_ELF_REL=n"
```

Is this the correct way to do so or has this no effect on the kernel parameters?

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing "kernel boot parameters" with "kernel configuration parameters". To do what you want, even though you don't want to, you need to modify the kernel configuration file and re-compile the kernel.

Because they are compile time directives, it is not possible to change kernel configuration parameters via the grub command line. However, and depending on what they are, sometimes the users objectives can still be achieved via kernel command line in grub. For example, say my kernel configuration had `CONFIG_X86_INTEL_PSTATE=y`. I can still tell the kernel not to use the Intel P-state CPU frequency scaling driver via this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="intel_pstate=disable"
```

in grub. So even though it is compiled into the kernel, it will not be used.

Comment: If I understand your answer correctly you want to say that it is not possible to change `kernel configuration parameters` via grub. Is this correct?

Comment: yes, it is not possible. I attempted to clarify my answer.

Comment: Yes, I know that I can change some(?) kernel configuration parameter via grub. But it looks that there is no general way. Do you know if I can change the requested kernel parameter by grub? By the way I didn’t confuse kernel parameter and boot parameter :-)

Comment: You can not change any kernel configuration parameter via grub. Since I don't know what your objective is, I can not comment further. You could review `Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt` (old location is `Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt`) yourself, but I didn't see anything obvious therein.

Comment: I have posted an Ubuntu bug : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-xenial/+bug/1656670 and I am looking for a workaround.